# jQuery script issue (not working when I click for the second time)

Tags: jquery

When I click on the link it will show a pop-up(Twitter Bootstrap) and in that I have a select field called country, and when I select US it will auto-populate all the states of US in the another select field, else it will show a text field.

It is working when I click link for the first time, after closing and when I click the link for a second time, the script is not getting loaded.

I don't know the reason, please help me out.

Here is the script :

```
div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4">
  <%= f.label :Country %>
  <%= country_select("job", "country",[], :include_blank => "Select country") %>
</div>
<div class="span4">  
  <%= label_tag "State"%>
  <%= f.select :state, options_for_select(Contact::STATES) %>
  <%= text_field_tag "state_name", "", :class => "text_state"%>
</div>
<div class="span4"> 
  <%= label_tag "City"%>
  <%= f.text_field :city %>
</div>
</div><br/>

<script>

$("#job_country").click(function() {
$a = $("#job_country option:selected").text();
if ($a == "United States") {
  $("#job_state").show();
  $(".text_state").hide();
}
else
{
  $("#job_state").hide();
  $(".text_state").show();
}
});
});  
</script>
```

Comment: please share the html also

Comment: hey i updated my code to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that job_country is a select,, try ti change the event from `click()` to  `change()`.

Use `$(this).val()` to take the value from your select

And insert your script inside `document.ready()`

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#job_country").change(function() {
     $a = $(this).val();
     if ($a == "United States") {
       $("#job_state").show();
       $(".text_state").hide();
     }
     else
     {
       $("#job_state").hide();
       $(".text_state").show();
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: stole?! I don't think so... :) we have posted same time and I have added more lines of comment @ManjunathHegde

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri : You have posted before Manjunath

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are trying to trigger the function on change of select box

```
 $("#job_country").change(function() {
    $a = $(this).val();
    if ($a == "United States") {
      $("#job_state").show();
      $(".text_state").hide();
    }
    else
    {
      $("#job_state").hide();
      $(".text_state").show();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

If you are trying to trigger the event, after popup load it failed for the click event

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').on('click','#job_country'function() {
         $a = $(this).val();
         if ($a == "United States") {
           $("#job_state").show();
           $(".text_state").hide();
         }
         else
         {
           $("#job_state").hide();
           $(".text_state").show();
         }
       });
    });
```

Comment: .live() is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

you might need this:

```
<select id="job_country">
  <option value="United States">UnitedStates</option>
  <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="other" selected>Other</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="job_state" style="display:none">
  <option value="Newyork">Newyork</option>
  <option value="Losangles">Losangles</option>
  <option value="other" selected>Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class='text_state' value="Please type state name.">
<script>
$("#job_country").change(function () {
    var a = $("#job_country option:selected").val();
    //alert(a);

    if (a == "United States") {
        $("#job_state").show();
        $(".text_state").hide();
    } else {
        $("#job_state").hide();
        $(".text_state").show();
    }

});
</script>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A7JBx/1